# Almacenar en SESSION php

Tags: php, base-de-datos, variables, session

¿Es recomendable en una web multi idiomas ir almacenando los datos de las traducciones en **$_SESSION**?

Es decir, que tengo las traducciones en un archivo json, y para no ir abriendo el json cada vez que el mismo usuario acceda a la misma página los guardo en una variable de **SESSION**.

Tampoco no sé si sería recomendable ir almacenando los datos de las bases de datos en la SESSION para no volver a ejecutarla en caso de que sea el mismo

Comment: Tu pregunta luce basada en opiniones y eso generaría su cierre, lee [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En caso de que quieras almacenar esa clase de información, yo optaría por usar cookies.
Para insertar la cookie debes usar la función setcookie:

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
```

Aquí te dejo todos los parametros que acepta:

```
setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain, secure, httponly);
```